# emacs error on startup when i try and bind keys to wdired-mode-map

Tags: key-bindings, init-file, keymap

emacs gives me an error when i try the bind keys to wdired-mode-map:

```
(define-key wdired-mode-map (kbd "TAB") 'my-mark-file-name-forward )
(define-key wdired-mode-map (kbd "-") 'my-mark-file-name-backward )
(define-key wdired-mode-map (kbd "<f2>") 'my-mark-file-name-for-rename )
```

the error is:

```
Symbol's value as variable is void: wdired-mode-map
```

any clue what im doing wrong here? i always define-key for other modes like this an never encountered an issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wdired-mode-map` only becomes available after wdired-mode is used, if you want
to change the keymap, you can use "mode hook" (`wdired-mode-hook`)

```
(add-hook 'wdired-mode-hook
          (lambda () (define-key wdired-mode-map ...)))
```

or `with-eval-after-load`

```
(with-eval-after-load "wdired"
  (define-key wdired-mode-map ...))
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, when a variable or function is `void`, the most likely suspect is that the applicable library has not yet been loaded.  Two common approaches are to `require` the library beforehand with `(require 'wdired)` or use `(eval-after-load "wdired" '(progn ...))`.  Many people prefer the second option because Emacs starts up faster.